# Check50 "not a valid ASCII Ouput" on pset2 caesar

Tags: c, cs50

I completed the caesar assignment on cs50 and tested it on my terminal and it worked perfectly, but on check50 is kept failing some tests.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int getkey(string k);
string cipher(string s, int key);
int key;
int p;
int q;

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Allow 2 command line inputs
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        // Assign a local string to allow char scan
        string s = argv[1];

        // Check if all inputs are numbers
        for (int i = 0; s[i] != 0; i++)
        {
            if (s[i] < 48 || s[i] > 57)
            {
                printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
        // Get key from string
        int cipherkey = getkey(s);

        // Get user text
        string text = get_string("plaintext: ");

        // Calculate ciphertext and print
        string ciphertext = cipher(text, cipherkey);
        printf("ciphertext: %s\n", ciphertext);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
}

// Change string to int. Turns out theres already a function for this called atoi()
int getkey(string k)
{
    key = 0;
    for(int i = 0, conv = 0, n = strlen(k); k[i] != 0; i++, n--)
    {
        // Calcute the placevalue
        p = pow(10, n-1);
        conv = k[i] - 48; // Convert to int
        key = key + (conv * p); // Sum up
    }
    return key % 26;
}

// Cipher text
string cipher (string s, int key)
{
    for(int i = 0; s[i] != 0; i++)
    {
       if(islower(s[i]))
       {
           s[i] = s[i] + key;
           while(s[i] > 122)
           {
               s[i] = (s[i] - 123) + 97;
           }
       }
       else if(isupper(s[i]))
       {
           s[i] = s[i] + key;
           while(s[i] > 90)
           {
               s[i] = (s[i] - 91) + 65;
           }
       }
    }
    return s;
}
```

with error message

```
:) caesar.c compiles.
:) encrypts "a" as "b" using 1 as key
:( encrypts "barfoo" as "yxocll" using 23 as key
    output not valid ASCII text
:) encrypts "BARFOO" as "EDUIRR" using 3 as key
:) encrypts "BaRFoo" as "FeVJss" using 4 as key
:) encrypts "barfoo" as "onesbb" using 65 as key
:( encrypts "world, say hello!" as "iadxp, emk tqxxa!" using 12 as key
    output not valid ASCII text
:) handles lack of argv[1]
:) handles non-numeric key
:) handles too many arguments
```

I wrote the code without knowing the "atoi" function so i implemented a function called getkey() to return key. when i returned key normally, it failed.

```
:( encrypts "barfoo" as "onesbb" using 65 as key
Output not a valid ASCII text
```

Until i returned key % 26;

I dont know why check50 isnt working although the program works well on my terminal. Please help.

Updated code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

string cipher(string s, int key);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Allow 2 command line inputs
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        // Assign a local string to allow char scan
        string s = argv[1];

        // Check if all inputs are numbers
        for (int i = 0; s[i] != 0; i++)
        {
            if (s[i] < 48 || s[i] > 57)
            {
                printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
        // Get key from string
        int cipherkey = atoi(s);

        // Get user text
        string text = get_string("plaintext: ");

        // Calculate ciphertext and print
        string ciphertext = cipher(text, cipherkey);
        printf("ciphertext: %s\n", ciphertext);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }
}

// Cipher text
string cipher (string s, int key)
{
    for(int i = 0; s[i] != 0; i++)
    {
        if(islower(s[i]))
        {
            s[i] = (int) s[i] + key;
            while(s[i] > 'z')
            {
                s[i] = (s[i] - 123) + 97;
            }
        }
        else if(isupper(s[i]))
        {
            s[i] = (int) s[i] + key;
            while(s[i] > 'Z')
            {
                s[i] = (s[i] - 91) + 65;
            }
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: `k[i] - 48` You should never use such "magic numbers". If you mean the character `'0'` you should use `'0'` and not some number.

Comment: If you already know that your `getkey` implementation causes problems, you could remove all the other code and just post this function together with your test cases.

Comment: If the `getkey` function is meant to convert a string to a number, it does not make any sense to add `%26`. That seems to be some limitation of your encryption mechanism. Then handle it during encryption or after parsing that string. But do not pollute that function with such an unrelated feature

Comment: No time to study your cipher function except to point out the `string` hides the fact that you are dealing with `signed chars`... When you add a value to (especially) a lower case signed char, the result can be a negative number... `-127 to +128` in 8 bits signed... Maybe copy the `char` to an `int` so there are sufficient bits to stay positive and allow `>` to work as you intend...

Comment: @Gerhardh I've gotten rid of the getkey function and used atoi(), Ive changed some of the magic numbers like 90 and 122 into 'z' and 'Z' but it still return the error message

Comment: Please add the updated code to your question below your original code.

Comment: @Fe2O3 um sorry, I don't really understand what you mean.

Comment: The ASCII code for the letter 'x' is 120 (base 10). The maximum value that can be stored in a 'signed char' is 127 (range correction -128 to +127)... If you add '8' or more to that character value, the value will overflow (undefined behaviour) and wrap around to become a negative value. Negative values are always "<" positive values, so the conditional is always false... Simply declare `int cpy = str[i]` and use `cpy` in the testing. I see you've tried casting to `int` but then value stored back into `char`.... Doesn't work that way!

Comment: @Fe2O3 woah! Thanks man! It works! and i have absolutely no idea why :/. I'm trying to read through your messages to understand why but hm, my brain hurts. Thanks again.

Comment: @Gerhardh Thanks also bro.  You helped me clean up my code, i had a feeling it was off somehow, was just trying multiple things the internet suggested to get it to work without understansing em properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've rewritten the function trying to avoid going to far making corrections and improvements. Now, the copy is actually unnecessary, but I hope it helps you understand that a "signed (8 bit) char" is not 'wide' enough to use in calculations that lead to overflow...

Please read the following and try to follow along.

```
string cipher( string s, int key ) {
    for( int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++ ) {
        if( !isalpha( s[i] ) )
            continue;

        int copy = (int)s[i]; // unnecessary casting, but...

        // transform ASCII value into 0-25 range
        if( islower( s[i] ) )
            copy = copy - 'a';
        else // must be uppercase
            copy = copy - 'A';

        copy = (copy + key) % 26;

        // transform enciphered MODULO back into ASCII char
        if( islower( s[i] ) )
            copy = copy + 'a';
        else // must be uppercase
            copy = copy + 'A';

        s[i] = copy;
    }

    return s;
}
```

Quiet night, so I thought I'd rewrite the rewrite just to see what it looked like...

```
string cipher( string s, int key ) {
    for( char *cp = s; *cp; cp++ )
        if( isalpha( *cp ) ) {
            char c = "Aa"[ !!islower(*cp) ];
            *cp = (char)(((*cp - c + key) % 26) + c);
        }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: I understand it a little better. Thanks.

Comment: @rzsamrio It's always best to make code as simple as possible to read and understand. It's said that you will spend 100x (or more) hours looking at code as you will writing code. Give yourself a break :-)